# Does the Xcode thread santizer work for both Debug and Release builds

Tags: swift, xcode

Does the Xcode thread santizer work for both Debug and Release builds in XCode?

I have a project where the sanitizer shows an error with a release build, but not debug build. I want to check I can run it in release mode.

Comment: "where the sanitizer shows an error with a release build" What error? It sounds like it's working correctly if it's detecting a thread issue.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted to check – as this error doesn't show in a debug build.

Comment: So your question is backwards? It seems the question is whether you have to be Release mode for the sanitizer to work. — Anyway, I think it works in both; threading in Debug and Release mode works differently, so it isn't surprising if you get different results.

Comment: It *does* work in both Debug and Release mode.

Comment: Still confusing: “Do you have to be in Debug mode for TS to work? ... shows an error with a release build, but not debug build ... can I run it in release mode”